# generating dynamic sql in c

Tags: sql, c, oracle, proc

I have to generate a c program that can generate a dynamic update sql and execute it.
The table name, no of columns to be updated and columns in where clause are known
only during run time.So i split my program into 2 functions:

1)**CheckTableExists** - checks whether the table provided by user exists in db.
**Successfully implemented.**

2)**UpdateFunc** - generates the sql string from data provided by user and executes
the query.

I am having issues in second function.I accept no of columns,names and values to be
updated from user. I then use a for loop and append the names and values to my sql 
string:

sqlstring = Update tabname set colname = colval,colname = colval where

Then i accept where clause data and append it to my string. So my final string is:

sqlstring = Update tabname set colname = colval,colname = colval where whcolname = whcolval

But when i execute it my program hangs.Can somebody just tell me what should be the
ideal approach to execute second function.

Comment: What does your exact SQL string look like?  Can you run it directly in your RDBMS?  Nothing above looks incorrect unless your values are varchars and need apostrophes.

Comment: `Pro*C`? Why take the arguments for `WHERE` clause, just take complete query in `string` format and do `EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :strSQL;`

Comment: Okk that was my real doubt whther we require to pass host varibales to strSQL. so can my string be like this                              EXEC SQL Update tabname set colname= colval where whcolname = whcolval.   All the above are c char arryays

Comment: I am actually using a code for reference. That code selects data dynamically. The sqlstring is generated using sprintf :            sprintf(SqlString.arr,"EXEC SQL SELECT :fname,:last_name,:age from :tab_name where :id = :val"); fname,last_name,age,id  carry column names ,tab_name -> tablename. But all these were passed as in structure from one class to another. SO it was easy . But i am confused how should i generate that string.

Comment: Add Oracle to tagnames of the post. The one where you use `:` is called `binding variables`. I was talking about without Binding inside `.PC` proc file. If all the columns are Varchar/Int then you can prepare a valid SQL outside `.PC` file/function. In the above case strSQL was valid SQL statement without placeholders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strSQL` will be a valid SQL statement without placeholders for binding. This is suitable for queries with numeric and varchar2 variables. For binary you may have to implement functions say bin2hex() and hex2bin() in Oracle.

A simple function like:

```
int Exec_Query(sql_context sqlCtx, char *strSQL)
{

//    struct sqlca sqlca;

    /* Sanity checks for sqlCtx and strSQL */

    EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR GOTO QueryErr;  

    /* Set the context */
    EXEC SQL CONTEXT USE :sqlCtx;  

    /* Execute the query */
    EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :strSQL; 

    EXEC SQL COMMIT; 

    return 0;

QueryErr:
    /* printf("Err: Failure in Executing Query\n"); */
    /* printf("Debug: <%s>",sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc); */
    return -1;
}
```

Which through a Pro*C compiler will give a working C file.

Comment: thnx will try and let u know!!